# Classify all finite groups with property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Classify all finite groups $G$ with the following property:

for every $H\vartriangleleft G$ there exists $K<G$ such that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $K$.

My poor abstract-algebraic imagination doesn't bring any ideas...

Comment: Simple finite groups clearly verify this property. Finite abelian groups also verify this property. There is a group of order $p^3$ which has this property for $p>3$ (the Heisenberg group). Whereas non-commutative groups of order $8$ do not verify this property. Well it seems pretty messy. Don't you have $G/H$ isomorphic to $K$ $\underline{and}$ $K\cap H$ is trivial ?

Comment: I don't, or my notes are incomplete (what happens rarely, but is possible)

Comment: @ClémentGuérin Doesn't $D_8$ have this property? All nontrivial quotients are isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}/2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $D_8$ contains both types of subgroups...